# How do I update an existing table with a few hundred records with a unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017, row-number, unique-id

I am having trouble updating an existing table (with a few hundred records)  with a unique ID

The table is called BHIVE.ProjectDataGroupDetail and has a few hundred records.
The Field I'd like to update is called ProjectDataGroupDetailID. I am also updating a 2nd field with the value '1'.

My stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [BHIVE].[PopulateProjectDataGroupDetail]  
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE BHIVE.ProjectDataGroupDetail
SET ProjectDataGroupDetailID = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY SampleProjects), ProjectDataGroup = 1 
    
End
```

I am getting the error :

```
Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses
```

Comment: Please, add tag of your DBMS not to guess it by syntax elements. Also you should provide the table structure and on what condition you need to reset that row numbering.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: thanks for the tip!

Comment: can I update this post with an additional tag or is it just at time of creation.

Comment: @ChanelGabb You can use [edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64981263/how-do-i-update-an-existing-table-with-a-few-hundred-records-with-a-unique-id/64982691?noredirect=1#) under your post to enrich your question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`MERGE` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for this.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=85c2a0a760213d45b8acf83a5ae53377)

```
merge into ProjectDataGroupDetail as t
using (
  select id, row_number() over(partition by some_grouping_col order by id) as rn
  from ProjectDataGroupDetail
) as s
  on t.id = s.id
when matched then update
  set
    ProjectDataGroupDetailID = s.rn,
    ProjectDataGroup = 1
;
```

Comment: I had to remove the partition by statement and this worked ! Thankyou!!

Comment: merge into ProjectDataGroupDetail as t
using (
  select SampleProjects, row_number() over(order by SampleProjects) as rn
  from ProjectDataGroupDetail
) as s
  on t.SampleProjects = s.SampleProjects
when matched then update
  set
    ProjectDataGroupDetailID = s.rn,
    ProjectDataGroup = 1
;

Comment: @ChanelGabb You're welcome! I've put it there for more general case, where you can need to reset numbering on some group of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
UPDATE
BHIVE.ProjectDataGroupDetail

SET ProjectDataGroupDetailID = RowNumber
FROM
(
SELECT
Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY SampleProjects) Rownumber
FROM
BHIVE.ProjectDataGroupDetail 
) source
```

Comment: Usually a unique Id is auto generated so you just leave it out of the query. If ProjectDataGroupDetailID is a unique identifier then you cannot update it.

Comment: The table already has data in it. I've added a new field and need to update this field with sequential numbers for the already existing records

Comment: Then just run that update statement. Let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: Thank you I've run this and good news is it didn't error when I ran and executed the stored procedure. Looks like it should work but The ProjectDataGroupDetailID field hasn't updated.

Comment: UPDATE
ProjectDataGroupDetail

SET ProjectDataGroupDetailID = RowNumber

FROM
(
SELECT
Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY ProjectDataGroup) Rownumber, ProjectDataGroup = 2 
FROM
ProjectDataGroupDetail ) source
 
End